# In jQuery jsplot graph, the map does not appear when the page becomes visible, only when keyup function occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin which shows a graph using jsplot. But the graph is not visible initially, only after a field is changed in the input associated with the graph values it begins to show. Form the code it is clear that keyup event is used to call the function. But how can I show the graph when the page appears, which event or any other trick?
I am new to jsplot and weak in jQuery. Could not find a suitable answer for this.

Adding part of the code below

```
jQuery("input").keyup(function (e) {
        var active_input = jQuery(this).parents("#rent-sell-form").eq(0).find(":input");

        /* Code to plot graph goes here */
    }).keyup();
```